# Change Bootstrap's Color Scheme

Tags: css, colors, bootstrap-4

Years ago when I first met Bootstrap, when it still called itself Twitter Bootstrap, I searched how to colorize it, changing the default white/blue color scheme.

I remember there was even an online tool I could upload a random picture and it would generate a separate CSS file with its most noticeable colors, which I also could edit here and there in case their algorithm didn't match my wishes.

Today, using Bootstrap 4, not only I didn't find such online tool anymore but I also surprisingly didn't find anything at all related to a way to change the color scheme of Bootstrap **version 4** (let's emphasize that)

Is there anything like this nowadays that would help automate a little bit the process?

> Note: Preferably without requiring knowledge of LESS/SASS/SCSS nor anything like that

Answer (score 1):

I think since Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha, the customizer websites like bootswatchr are not using it yet.

So for now you can use the options to override the basic settings :

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/